# Check if a file has been modified between commits

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a file on git, this file may be modified or not in between commits, and I need to execute certain steps only if this file is modified.

Should I query the git status for each commit and check if the file is in the modified list? I get the commits trigger from our Jenkins server, but I am not sure if there is a better way to do this.

I could get X commits between changes on this file, so I want to be sure to execute the extra steps only when the file change.

Comment: Try `git log <start-commit>..<end-commit> -- <file-path>`. I haven't run it so I'm not sure if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Would putting all the steps that you need to execute when a file changes into a separate job and setting up the git polling to ignore everything except that file work for you?

For example:

1. Clicking on "Additional Behaviors" on the target git repository
2. Select "Polling ignore commits in certain paths" from the drop down list.
3. Add the file as the only region in the "Included Regions" list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I need to check if our admin can do that on the Jenkins server. I work "downstream", so I can only get what the server throws at me, in this case I get a build mail from Jenkins, which trigger my shell script to query the git repo.